# open new window not in tabGroup when tableRow is clicked (titanium)

Tags: javascript, titanium

I have 4 windows all linked together with tabs. on the last tab (helpTab), it has a table with two rows, to 'email for help' or 'watch tutorial.' I would like the user to be able to click on either row which will take them to either the 'emailWindow' or the 'videoWindow'.  These windows are not in the tabGroup. I was trying to add a navGroup to the helpTab window, but when I do this the simulator will not run.

I don't really understand the way navGroups work within a tabGroup. Can anyone suggest a way that I can add a navGroup to a tabGroup? or if this is even possible? (i have only written code for the emailWindow so far. Because I can't get this to work, I thought there is not point in writing incorrect code twice!) I hope I have provided enough information. Thank you

```
var helpWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    //code to create window
});

helpWindow.open();

var rootWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var navGroup = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
    window: helpWindow
});
rootWindow.add(navGroup);
rootWindow.open();

// add table etc (normal code with 2 rows)

row1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    navGroup.open(emailWindow);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

solved:

I moved

```
rootWindow.open();
```

into the eventListener

Comment: Let me just add that NavigationGroup is deprecated in the beta release and will be replaced by NavigationWindow from SDK 3.2.0 on.